# Python 3 how can i structure files?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm very new to pyhton so forgive me.
My question it how I can structure a file. For example I want to save multiple cooking recipes in a file. The program then should find the whole recipe with the ingerdients just by knowing its name.
I have tried to find answers in the internet but I seem not to find the right search term. So my question is just for what term do I have to google to find something that helps me?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking to convert a text file into a dictionary.  I would recommend using a JSON structure.  See [this page](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-to-a-file-in-python/).  If scope of your project is bigger than yourself using it, you would be better off using a database.  Check out MongoDB.

Comment: Thank you very much Sir. That helped me alot.